# Grub Boot Error

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 doesn't boot after Ubuntu install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10410/windows-7-doesnt-boot-after-ubuntu-install)

I installed Ubuntu, and it runs succesfully, but I can't boot the Windows 7. Every time I choose Windows 7 to run, it returns to the same boot screen menu.

May be its because I selected the Boot loader partition the same as Window 7 Loader partition.

Help me fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/10410/3940

Answer (score 0):

With a Win 7 DVD repair the bootloader then with a live cd reinstall GRUB

- [Installing Windows after Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Installing%20Windows%20After%20Ubuntu)
- [Recovering Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)