# Windows partition not booting

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, ntfs

Using Clonezilla, I cloned a Windows 7 installation from the first partition on one drive to the first partition on a second larger drive and then installed Ubuntu into the second partition (same configuration as the original drive, just newer version instead of old).

Ubuntu detected the Windows 7 partition properly and added it to the grub menu. However, when I choose the win7 option in grub, I just get a black screen and blinking cursor. How can I fix this?

@CentaurusA: Here is the output of boot info script output http://pastebin.com/778RP7Lp

Comment: Is the original hard drive still installed on the system?

Comment: you may need to [restore your Windows PBR](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10410/windows-7-doesnt-boot-after-ubuntu-install/10418#10418)

Comment: @Mark: Original drive is no longer present.  @Takkat, I'm trying to find out if there is a way to do this without having to reinstall grub / ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Boot Info Script (http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/).  This will produce the file RESULTS.txt that describes each disk/partition on your system.  Check that GRUB2 is identifying the partitions correctly by comparing the descriptors used in the menuentries in /boot/grub/grub.cfg match those in the results file.  I have an issue where GRUB2 mis-identifies my Vista and Windows' recovery partitions and doesn't boot correctly as a result.  The fix was to create a custom boot menu (see http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My inexperienced eyes don't see anything wrong in the output. There are no recovery partitions of any sort either :/

Answer (score 0):

1.
Boot from Windows Recovery CD, Windows Recovery Partition, or Installation CD

2.
Click on "[Repair your computer](http://www.pctechbytes.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/windows_7_startup_repair.jpg)"

3.
Click on "[Startup Repair](http://cdn2.mytechguide.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/windows-7-startup-repair-71.jpg)"

4.
Windows should now boot properly

Comment: I was look for a solution that would not entail reinstalling grub again after repairing Windows.