# Dual boot problem with Windows XP

Tags: dual-boot

My computeres run Windows XP at the moment. I have tried an installation of Ubuntu on one machine but have experience considerable problems with booting after installation of Ubuntu - the dual boot menu fails to boot Windows XP. I have considered wiping the hard drive then installing Ubuntu followed by partitioning the drive then reinstalling Windows XP and an alternative boot manager - EasyBSD - to overcome the problem mentioned above. Will this work or must I stick with the Grub bootloader in the Ubuntu package?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 won't boot after installing Ubuntu 11](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99584/windows-7-wont-boot-after-installing-ubuntu-11)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to restore your Windows boot entry. Just run "recommended repair".

Comment: Sorry but have tried Boot-Repair as suggested but it didn't solve the problem. It appears that it is impossible to dual boot Windows XP and Ubuntu or similar Linux distributions with any certainty if the Grub bootloader is present.