# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongwith Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Today I installed Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 7 and now only 1 operating system ie Ubuntu in working I want to use Windows also what should I do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 won't boot after installing Ubuntu 11](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99584/windows-7-wont-boot-after-installing-ubuntu-11)

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal and type: `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Add the following line:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
chainloader +1
}
```

by appropriately modifying the location of windows 7 in your computer.
Then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Install ReFind, it will handle the Grub bootloader and the windows UEFI bootloader for you, and simply when you boot it will give you the choice of what to boot. http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/