# No Boot of either Win7 or Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

After an overwrite of the ubuntu in a dual boot with Win7, laptop won't boot.  The option on re-installing said Replace not wipe the disk. Gparted says that the first partition is Fat32 and only 487 MiB and it's says efi (my machine only has legacy). The second or ubuntu now is 293.89 Gib with Swap at3.73 Gib. 
Question is, is my Windows gone?

Comment: How did you perform 'overwrite'?

Comment: Is EFI mode "ON" in bios? if bothe legacy and EFI modes are turned ON, please turn off EFI mode and try again..if it doesn't boot reinstall ubuntu. (does not gparted show any windows partition? try a live cd and make sure that your windows exists or not)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 won't boot after installing Ubuntu 11](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99584/windows-7-wont-boot-after-installing-ubuntu-11)

Comment: What version and did you use an auto install option to reinstall. You may have overwritten entire drive. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192 Fixed but older ISOs not updated.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (available in the `boot-info-script` package in Ubuntu). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt` with technical information on your installation. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your document here. Without the technical details, any answer will be a wild guess.

Comment: Used an install cd, existing dual boot withWin7, said I could REPLACE older ubuntu and NOT wipe disk. Did and No boot EITHER. Gparted says first partition is Fat32 and id is efi and flagged boot. Gparted recovery doesn't work. Several things I'm asking, Is that Fat32 partition whats left of my Windows and why is it so small? Is it recoverable? Windows repair disk won't work. At  this point, I'm not caring about the ubuntu on the machine. And lastly, Should I just go ahead and recover my Win7 with my disks.  Again, No UEFI OPTION in BIOS. Here is the Pastebin:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/11593545/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and find answer.first I install windows and boot live ubuntu cd then ubuntu 15.04 automatically divided hdd two part one ntfs and else ext4 and install on ext4 and boot both os normally

Answer (score 0):

> Gparted says that the first partition is Fat32 and only 487 MiB and it's says efi (my machine only has legacy).

Your Boot Info Script output indicates that this is an [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) It has the EFI version of GRUB installed on it. Although it's possible to create an ESP and place EFI boot loaders on it using a BIOS-based computer, the Ubuntu installer should never do this. Thus, there are really only two possibilities:

- You've discovered a bug in the Ubuntu installer.
- You're mistaken and your computer uses an EFI.

The second seems more likely to me. Most computers sold since mid-2011, and a few sold even several years before that, have EFIs. Many of these computers also support BIOS-mode booting via an EFI subsystem called the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), so such computers might well boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode; but they are EFI-based and are perfectly capable of booting EFI-based OSes.

> Question is, is my Windows gone?

Yes. Your Boot Info Script output includes:

```
Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       999,423       997,376 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2         999,424   617,328,639   616,329,216 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda3     617,328,640   625,141,759     7,813,120 Swap partition (Linux)
```

There's no Windows partition there. If you have important Windows files, see [this question and answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) for advice about recovering your data. (Hint: You almost certainly won't be able to recover it all, but if you put in enough effort, you can probably recover a few files.)

> Is that Fat32 partition whats left of my Windows and why is it so small?

No, it's the ESP. It was probably created by the Ubuntu installation. A typical size for an ESP is between 100MiB and 600MiB, although it could theoretically be just about any size that can hold a FAT (preferably FAT32) filesystem.

> Again, No UEFI OPTION in BIOS.

The [Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) and its version-2.x variant, Unified EFI (UEFI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uefi) is a type of firmware that *replaces* the old [Basic Input/Output System (BIOS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) firmware. I know that a lot of people, and even manufacturers and software developers, use the term "BIOS" as if it were synonymous with "firmware," but that just muddies the water. In particular, EFI/UEFI is *not* a BIOS option, and thinking of it as such will lead you astray. Indeed, I've seen EFIs that have "BIOS setup utility" or something similar plastered across their setup screens. This is confusing, and it's the reason that I and a few others (like [Adam Williamson](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)) are so adamant about not applying the term "BIOS" to EFIs.

Anyhow, stepping back from the soapbox, the point is that the lack of any option called "EFI" or "UEFI" in your firmware doesn't really indicate anything. Also, some EFIs do have CSMs, but the options that control EFI/UEFI-mode booting vs. BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting may be labeled "legacy mode" or "CSM." If you're not familiar with the terminology, you could easily skip over these options, not understanding their importance. Options might also be hidden unless and until some other unrelated-sounding option is set appropriately. Also, the settings and algorithms that control an EFI's boot mode (EFI/EFI vs. BIOS/CSM/legacy) vary greatly from one machine to another, and can be quite opaque. Thus, predicting the boot mode can be a tricky thing.

The bottom line, I'm afraid, is that your Windows installation is hosed. At this point, it sounds like your best bet is to re-install both it and Ubuntu from scratch, possibly attempting file-level recovery of your personal files first.

Comment: Thank you all for posting suggestions and especially to you Rod for taking the time to answer point by point. When I'm trying to restore an old radio , I look to the forums and hope a Guru shows up that lets me know how much I really need to know, and you are that guy for me here. Guess I'll chalk it up to experience. As for Ubuntu, might try to install 14.04 right after recovering Windows. Hey what's to lose then?