# Windows 7 installed on ubuntu but system not able to boot windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have recently installed windows 7 on ubuntu.. This is how I did it- first I made a ntfs partition for my windows 7 installation, then I made a bootable usb from an iso file of windows 7 , and I  booted from the usb. Every thing was fine, all the files expanded and installed , then my system restarted to complete the installation but instead of booting windows 7, it again started to boot from the usb. After removing the usb, it booted to ubuntu instead of windows... what could be the problem?
I could see all the files installed in the windows 7 partition from ubuntu system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 won't boot after installing Ubuntu 11](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99584/windows-7-wont-boot-after-installing-ubuntu-11)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `sudo update-grub` to make grub recognize the Windows installation?

Maybe you have to modify some settings in `/etc/default/grub`, too. For example, `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: I updated the grub, which showed option to boot to windows on the boot loader. I even boot into windows but installation completion didn't happen , it showed this message "Windows Setup could not configure Windows to run on this computer's hardware"