# WIndows 7 wont load?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, bootloader

I installed ubuntu in a separate partition and my windows 7 was in a separate partition. so in the grub screen when I choose to load from from windows 7 it wont boot and again the grub screen comes back. I tried to use a USB stick with windows7 loader to repair my windows7 but even the usb wont be recognized and i cant boot anything from the USB either !! what should I do ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo parted -l` terminal command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 won't boot after installing Ubuntu 11](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99584/windows-7-wont-boot-after-installing-ubuntu-11)

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade your grub properly? I'd use super grub disk to fix it.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/