# GRUB Bootloader: Windows 8 Selection Not Working

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-8

I dual boot Windows 8 with Ubuntu 12.10, and when I turn on my laptop, I see the GRUB bootloader which is fine.  I see options for Ubuntu, Advanced Ubuntu options, Memory Test stuff, and finally Windows 8 (loader). When I select Windows 8 (loader), instead of going to the windows 8 loader, I simply see the GRUB bootloader again. It's kinda like I have the "option" to pick Windows 8, but GRUB doesn't like that option.

Has anyone encountered/solved this problem?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: The similar question has been answered for windows 7 here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/135272/how-to-boot-into-windows-7-when-grub-is-installed-in-the-windows-partition I guess it should work for this situation too.

Answer (score 0):

This little tool should help: [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home)

You can use it either from your Ubuntu disc, or via a dedicated rescue disc.

[image]