# Dual boot but now Win 7 does not boot, yet it is listed in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I know this has probably been answered many times before, so please send me links if you know.

I had Ubuntu 16.04 (three years ago), added Windows 7 (two years ago). Setting it up was very hard, but I did it successfully (Ubuntu on hda1, Win 7 on hda2).

Last month, I had a failure loading Ubuntu, but Windows could launch using a Boot CD and Boot Manager (pointed to hda2).
Last night I reinstalled Ubuntu (18.04) from a Live DVD in the original partition.
BUT
Now Windows cannot load, either from GRUB (it is listed there) or from one of those Boot Managers that point to hda2. Instead, I get a complicated series of error messages from grub (recalculating checksums, advice to run "bootsect /nt60 SYS /force", others).

Can this be easily fixed?

Comment: Need to see output of `grep -A10 -i Windows /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `sudo parted -l`.

Comment: Problem solved!
Elsewhere, I followed the following tip.

1. In grub, highlight Windows 7, then press the key <e>
2. Add the following line after the line <insmod ntfs>
    insmod ntldr
3. Replace the line 
     chainloader +1
     with he line
     ntldr ($root)/bootmgr

The original thread is here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/135272/how-to-boot-into-windows-7-when-grub-is-installed-in-the-windows-partition