# I am not able to boot into Windows 7 after Ubuntu 12.04 installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 doesn't boot after Ubuntu install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10410/windows-7-doesnt-boot-after-ubuntu-install)

I'm not able to boot into Windows 7. I am new to Ubuntu

Boot repair said:

> You can now reboot your computer.
>   Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda (500GB) disk!
>
> The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a `/boot` partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate `/boot` partition:] option of [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

What should I do?