# I installed Ubuntu and I can no longer boot win 7 or ubuntu. Can someone help me?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 doesn’t boot after Ubuntu install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10410/windows-7-doesnt-boot-after-ubuntu-install)

I installed Ubuntu and I can no longer boot win 7 or Ubuntu. Can someone help me?

I tried 3 ISO boot boot fixes and none worked on Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.10.

boot-repair   retatux   windows repair disk

Windows repair does not see the os.  I can see the files on /dev/sdc1 and Ubuntu on sda1.

What a mess.

Answer (score 1):

try from windows boot repair and from terminal

`bootrec /fixmbr`

if windows bootup try reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: windows repair disk doesnot show the win7 system because the disks are not visible.  Could this be a driver issue?

Comment: in some case ubuntu will convert fat32 to exfat and the windows not showing this disk , keep in mind you need to install windows on dev/sda as primary OS , try from ubuntu livecd via Gparted to show the disks type