# Windows hangs at grub's purple screen when dual booting in legacy boot mode

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I just installed my new computer (Gainward Z87X-UD4H, i7-4770, no video card). Due to some gaming, I installed Windows 7 first. Afterwards I installed Ubuntu 12.04  LTS. Now, my Ubuntu starts without any problems. Choosing Windows in grub, it hangs on grub's purple screen.

Again, this is not about a purple screen for Linux (for example, [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075)), it's more related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135272/), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99584) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10410). How I can debug/fix that?

For the protocol, I tried:

- [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and the [log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6439452/)
- [Here is a small movie](http://paste.dennis-boldt.de/download/20131120_212002.mp4), to demonstate the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try booting the windows install image/recovery disk and manually recovering the boot EFIs (with the `bootrec` and `bcdboot` commands).

Here is a complete guide: https://superuser.com/a/504360/275127 Helped me a lot when this happened to me.

When doing the above mentioned procedure, you should find a folder, on your EFI partition, with an "ubuntu" folder that hosts the ubuntu boot files. Create by following that post's guidelines the windows EFI files in a separate "microsoft" folder next to the "ubuntu" one.

Reboot, boot ubuntu normally, fire up boot-repair. Boot-repair will detect your new windows EFI files and proceed to add them to GRUB (the recommended settings option should suffice). If Boot-Repair asks if you want to back-up the windows EFI files, say yes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't use UEFI and Windows 8. My BIOS is configured on "Legacy only".

Comment: Huh. I would've asked before posting my answer but I don't have comment privileges. Well, I presume you could try the same procedure. I don't really know how do the ubuntu boot files set up during install in legacy mode, but you could still try recovering the windows boot. At least then you could use EasyBCD and then Live CD an ubuntu, install repair-boot and repair your grub. Here is a guide on recovering the windows boot. https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/

Comment: I ran `/fixmbr`, `/fixboot` and `/rebuildbcd` with bootrec.exe. Afterwards Windows was starting again. Then I did the boot-repair.Now I am back to my initial issue: Windows hangs at the purple screen.

Comment: Did you run boot-repair again? Sounds like a grub problem. Grub loads ok?

Comment: Yes, I ran boot-repair again. Grub loads ok. Ubuntu as well.

Comment: I'm sorry but this problem outruns me. Keep the boot-repair log URLs and head to the ubuntu forums or ask around in the chat (already did that but no reinforcements so far i'm afraid). You may have more chances there.